# GitLab Pipeline not able to parse double-dash in npm script property

Tags: jestjs, gitlab, gitlab-ci, stenciljs

I am using [stencil](https://stenciljs.com/docs/testing-overview) for building custom web components.

For testing, `stencil` is using jest CLI for running test files, here is the npm script command Im currently used for running those tests locally:

```json
{
    "test:base": "stencil test --spec --e2e",
    "test:all": "npm run test:base -- --coverage"
}
```

It is working perfectly when I am running it locally and the parameter `--coverage` in script `test:all` after double-dash can be parsed correctly:

```sh
$ npm run test:base -- --coverage --silent

> @heartlandone/vega@1.1.20 test:base
> stencil test --spec --e2e "--coverage" "--silent"

[59:13.9]  @stencil/core
[59:14.1]  v2.14.0 
[59:14.2]  testing e2e and spec files
[59:16.3]  build, vega, dev mode, started ...
[59:16.8]  transpile started ...
[59:18.3]  transpile finished in 1.45 s
[59:18.3]  copy started ...
[59:18.3]  generate lazy started ...
[59:18.5]  copy finished (17 files) in 210 ms
[59:21.0]  generate lazy finished in 2.76 s
[59:21.2]  build finished in 4.91 s

[59:21.2]  jest args: --coverage --silent --e2e --spec --max-workers=8
...
✨  Done in 36.94s.
```

However when I run it in gitlab pipeline:

```sh
> npm run test:base -- --coverage --silent
> @heartlandone/vega@1.1.20 test:base /builds/heartland1/vega/tiger/vega-stencil
> stencil test --spec --e2e "--coverage" "--silent"
[12:42.1]  @stencil/core
[12:42.5]  v2.14.0 
[12:42.9]  testing e2e and spec files
[12:51.4]  build, vega, dev mode, started ...
[12:51.6]  transpile started ...
[12:55.6]  transpile finished in 3.99 s
[12:55.6]  copy started ...
[12:55.6]  generate lazy started ...
[12:56.1]  copy finished (17 files) in 516 ms
[13:08.8]  generate lazy finished in 13.23 s
[13:08.9]  build finished in 17.55 s
[13:09.0]  jest args: --coverage --silent -- --e2e --spec
           --max-workers=8
No tests found, exiting with code 1
```

Seems like somehow the double dash is passed into jest directly hence making jest assuming `--e2e` and `--spec` is some keyword of the test suite hence filtering out all the existing test suites supposed to be run.

Not sure if this is a known issue or something can be resolved from user side?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem in a monorepo project where I'm using `nx` and `pnpm`.

### My problem

I observed the following behaviour:

1. When `cd`ing into the Stencil project and running `pnpm test`, the tests ran as expected.
2. When running `nx run stencil-project:test` no tests were found.

### Investigation

Having a closer look the following happens:

1. When running the second command, a double-dash was added to the final Stencil command: `stencil test --spec --e2e "--"`.
2. Stencil pushes all unknown args to Jest, see https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/main/src/testing/jest/jest-config.ts#L49
3. Unfortunately for that reason Jest receives the following command: `jest --max-workers=8 -- --e2e --spec --max-workers=8`
4. And now the problem happens: Everything after the double dash is used as the pattern `--e2e|--spec|--max-workers=8` to filter tests by their name.
5. As the pattern of course doesn't match any test, they get filtered out.

[Screenshot of final Jest error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TolOL.jpg)

### "Solution"

1. ❌ I started writing a Stencil-PR to remove the first `--` in the args, but I wasn't sure if NX or Stencil is to blame and therefore dropped it.
2. ❌ As an alternative I tried to ran Jest manually by recreating Stencil's Jest-config but unfortunately that didn't work out in the end. If someone would provide a solution for that, this would be better.
3. ✅ As it's super hard to influence Stencil's mechanisms (drawback of it being so opinionated) in the end I used a dirty hack: I added `'*'` to my test-scripts in package.json:

```json
{
    "test": "stencil test --spec --e2e '*'"
}
```

This breaks the pattern and instead runs all tests (`Invalid testPattern *|--e2e|--spec|--max-workers=8 supplied. Running all tests instead.`)

Mission accomplished. I hope this helps you, too.

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for the input. My question here is since the command I run in local and GitLab pipeline runner is the same which is `npm run test:base -- --coverage --silent`, why the second run is passing the double dash to the jest instead of keeping it as a flag for npm script just like what I run it locally.



I feel like it is more like a discrepancy in GitLab pipeline runner that not handle this script properly

Comment: I see... – did you try defining `test:all` as `stencil test --spec --e2e --coverage --silent`? This adds some redundancy but might fix your problem.